# Golang connect to Cubrid

Tags: sql, database, go, cubrid

I want to make a connection from Golang project to Cubrid DB, run on Windows and Linux.
I found the driver github.com/sabzil/cubrid but it don't work on windows.
Please give me a way to solve it!!!

Comment: did you install `gcc`?

Comment: Yes, I did.  but they show an error: library not found for -lnsl

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official CUBRID Go Driver.
https://github.com/CUBRID/cubrid-go